# angularjs: why is my directive as class specified by ng-class not recognized?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QR12CcwRztT35N3m9y3b?p=preview)

i need to include a directive as a class:

and i need to use this pattern:

`ng-class='{"some-directive":1'}`

but unfortunately the directive can only be registered in the pattern below (try it in the plunker link above):

`class='some-directive'`

The **main** problem is I want to register(include) the directive only to the "rename" option of my context menu:

`<li ng-class="{'renameDirective':(menu.name == 'Rename')}" ng-repeat="menu in contextmenu`

How would I achieve that?.. what's tougher is that I want to add an argument in renameDirective.. maybe like this :

`ng-class="{'renameDirective`*: directiveArg*`':(menu.name == 'Rename')}"`

is something like this: `<div renameDirective="directiveArg"></div>`

**UPDATE:**

As a wordy workaround, the code below can temporarily solve the issue. It is open for more improvements (I guess taking advantage of the ng-class directive is best, shortest/ cleanest approach).

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="menu in contextmenu">
  <div ng-switch on="menu">
    <div ng-switch-when="Rename">
      <button some-directive="Rename">button{{$index}}</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <button>button{{$index}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I had this semi-duplicate post as my reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636100/angularjs-dynamic-directives/17636418#17636418)

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class="{{menu.name=='Rename' && 'some-directive'}}">button2</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for that idea, and for the quick response. However, can you improve that expression so that some-directive accepts arguments? it's always good so we can parameterize.